# Unable to connect to postgres docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker

Following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3gnMSyX-XM I've entered the following:

```
➜  Downloads docker run -p 5432:5432 -d \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_DB=stripe-example \
-v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
postgres
5aaa30effe3282bd06c52b6c71f8343d24df041e9af11a38eb7a1e49453e3fa6
➜  Downloads psql stripe-example -h localhost -U postgres
psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

but am not sure why the role `postgres` doesn't exist, as it seems I've created that with `-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres`.

I'm expecting the following (screenshot from [this timestamp in the video](https://youtu.be/G3gnMSyX-XM?t=157)):

[image]

### Some updates.

> I looked at the docs and dash isn't allowed in database names. If your change the database name to stripe_example, it works. Remember to delete the pgdata volume first, before you try again.

```
➜  Downloads docker run -p 5432:5432 -d \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_DB=stripe_example \
-v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
postgres
da57c37c8306d5afdb54f8b3cf5e16aa67f97bce85ff4c8d3340e6f3288fb3cd
➜  Downloads psql stripe_example -h localhost -U postgres
psql: error: FATAL:  database "stripe_example" does not exist
```

Comment: If the `pgdata` volume already existed with a postgres database in it, then the startup script won't create a new user. If you think that might be the case, then you can remove the volume with the command `docker volume rm pgdata`.

Comment: @HansKilian thanks - after deleting that volume I instead get the error: `psql: error: FATAL:  database "stripe-example" does not exist`, which I thought was created with `-e POSTGRES_DB=stripe-example`

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the docs and dash isn't allowed in database names. If your change the database name to `stripe_example`, it works. Remember to delete the `pgdata` volume first, before you try again.

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.0/syntax525.htm#:~:text=Names%20in%20SQL%20must%20begin,but%20they%20will%20be%20truncated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.0/syntax525.htm#:%7E:text=Names%20in%20SQL%20must%20begin,but%20they%20will%20be%20truncated).

These commands should let you get to a state where I am at and where it works

```
docker volume rm pgdata
docker run --name=mypostgres -p 5432:5432 -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=stripe_example -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
docker exec -it mypostgres psql stripe_example -U postgres
```

One thing I do differently is that I run `psql` from inside the container, because I haven't got Postgres installed on my host. But that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I've edited the post - I tried this and it didn't work though

Comment: Weird. It works when I do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's more information I can add to the post to make it clearer?

Comment: If you look at the logs of the container, does it somewhere in the beginning say `CREATE DATABASE`?

Comment: I've added the commands I run to my answer.